# php Codeigniter and jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to call the codeigniter controller with ajax after the login. But when I execute it, the login page is only refreshed and ajax url isn't calling controller function of codeigniter.

I don't understand what happened. Please help?

Below is my code

```
function ValidateReg() {

        var username = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
    $.post("<?php echo site_url('Panel/login') ?>", {checkUser: username, checkPassword: password, action: "validateUser"},
        function (data) {
            var result = data + "";
            if (result.lastIndexOf("Success" > -1)) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/state'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    complete: function (done) {
                        console.log("Finished.")
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Here Panel and Dashboard are my two different Controllers

Comment: It depends on how  you are handling `login` click event. Show us the entire click event code please.

Comment: on login button i am calling script function.

Comment: Please show us that code, handling click event. That might help us to solve.

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn button text-uppercase" onclick="ValidateReg();">Login </button>

Comment: code in question i edited just.

Answer (score 1):

It gets refreshed because it's a submit button and it must be inside form. So it submits the form on click event.

What you need to do is make your function to return `false` on click of the button so that page doesn't get refreshed.

Update your HTML like this,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn button text-uppercase" onclick="return ValidateReg();">Login </button>
```

And your JS function would look something like this:

```
function ValidateReg() {

        var username = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('Panel/login') ?>", {checkUser: username, checkPassword: password, action: "validateUser"},
        function (data) {
            var result = data + "";
            if (result.lastIndexOf("Success" > -1)) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/state'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    complete: function (done) {
                        console.log("Finished.")
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
}
```

Comment: And how would you use asynchronous method as part of  `ValidateReg()`

Comment: `asynchronous` methods doesn't get affected with this code.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is go to the page `Dashboard/state` then using ajax is the wrong approach. You need to redirect to that page instead.

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('Panel/login') ?>", {checkUser: username, checkPassword: password, action: "validateUser"},
  function (data) {
    var result = data + "";
    if (result.lastIndexOf("Success" > -1))
    {
      console.log("Finished.");
      window.location = "<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/state'); ?>";
    }
  }
);
```

The other way to redirect with javascript would be done like this

```
window.location.replace("<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/state'); ?>");
```

which is probably better because it does not keep the originating page in the session history.

Comment: It Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

function ValidateReg() {

```
    var username = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
    $.post("<?php echo site_url('Panel/login') ?>", {checkUser: username, checkPassword: password, action: "validateUser"},
    function (data) {
        var result = data + "";
        if (result.lastIndexOf("Success" > -1)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Dashboard/state'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (done) {
                    console.log("Finished.")
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
```

}